# How did the phrase "beer me" originate?

Tags: history, terminology

The question says it all: where does the phrase "beer me" come from? And, is it widely used other than in the United States?

The phrase 'beer me' meaning, "give me a beer!"

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for English SE.

Answer (score 4):

In the opening scene of Three's Company, S07 E20 · Hair Today, Gone Tomorrow |
Apr 5, 1983, character Larry Dallas walks into the Regal Beagle and shouts to Mike the Bartender, "Beer me!"

Answer (score 1):

Good question, and no real origin that I can find; the oldest documented use that I could find is from The Simpsons, Episode 19, Season 2 (November 15, 1990):

Homer: "Marge, beer me! ... Don't toy with me woman."

[AS HEARD IN SEASON 2 - DEAD PUTTING SOCIETY](http://www.simpsonsforever.com/episodes/quotes/quote.php?id=413)

Comment: I was checking around on teh interwebz and a lady mentions this episode in this thread: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/can-i-beer-you.2505451/. But, a guy in the same thread says the phrase is much older...